# How to add values to dropdown in MVC3?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to add a dropdownlist in my form, with 2 values `userid` and `username` in my dropdownlist, and also I want to get the value selected by the user when I click the button. I'm new to MVC and so far, I have not worked on dropdownlist, tried few samples but nothing seems to be working the way I want.

Comment: Well, it won't be a dropdownlist, but a `<select>`. Did you know that?

Comment: Look here, there's a similar example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10649081/howcome-i-populate-selectlist-with-list-of-categories

Comment: Show us the samples that didn't work, you will know where you are going wrong ! !

Comment: i followed the below example, but getting the error as object reference not set to and instance of an object http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7142961/mvc3-dropdownlistfor-a-simple-example

Comment: @alwaysv Follow up: if you got the answer you were looking for, don't forget to mark it as correct. Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll jump lots of MVC3 concepts. If you're really new to ASP.NET MVC, you should take a look at some [tutorials](http://www.asp.net/mvc).

This code should help you:

**VIEW**

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("ACTION NAME", "CONTROLLER NAME"))
    {
        <select name="select">
            <option value="username" selected>User name</option>
            <option value="userid">User id</option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" />
    }
```

**ACTION**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ACTIONNAME(string select)
{
    //...
}
```

Please, note:

- `ACTION NAME` and `CONTROLLER NAME` at the `BeginForm` helper. You **will have to** modify this at your code
- The `select` name ("select") and the name of the argument at the action ("select"). This is not a coincidence, it's a convention. MVC uses the `name` attr to bind data
- The `selected` attribute at the option will make it the default option

Regards

Comment: where is the dropdown here? @html.dropdownlist?

Comment: @alwaysv I'm *not* using a HTML helper (such as `@Html.DropDownList`) to make sure that you understand that MVC is all about the markup, and that you're free to write it your own way. Also, you didn't said you wanted it using a HTML helper =)

Comment: yes,thanks a lot, this is working fine, and its simple,can u please tell how can i get the selected value?, let me be clear, i need to get selected value to my actionresult, based on that i wil perform some database operations

Comment: @alwaysv If you run this code, you'll notice that, at the **action**, `select` (the argument) will have the value selected by the user

Comment: yes, also how can i set default value as select for this dropdown?

Comment: @alwaysv Updated. I'd **strongly** recommend you to learn some HTML concepts. *W3Schools* and *Mozilla Developer Network* are great places for that.

Answer (score 0):

See one of the ways you can do it is send the list in a model property as the binding and for the value you can bind it to another property like :

```
public class YourModel 
{    
public List<UserList> OptionList { get; set; }
public String YourValue{get;set;}
}
public class UserList
{
   public String UserName{get;set;}
   public String UserId{get;set;}
}

@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.YourValue, Model.OptionList, "")
```

In the helper there are overided options which are used to specify the value and text.

And Remember : 
This is StackOverflow. 
***Even the Not working example which you have tried are important for the ones who try to help you since they are spending their precious bandwidths for u.***

Answer (score 0):

You don't need create a new model class for each view, just put this on controller:

```
ViewBag.FieldName = new SelectList(new List<SelectListItem>() {
    new SelectListItem { Value = "userid", Text = "User ID" },
    new SelectListItem { Value = "username", Text = "User name" }
});
```

And this on view:

```
@Html.DropDownList("FieldName")
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to create a collection of SelectListItem like:

   ```
   IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectList =
   from c in areaListResponse.Item
   select new SelectListItem
   {
     Text = c.AreaName,
     Value = c.Id.ToString()
   };
   ```
2. Pass this selectList to your view:

   ```
   return View(selectList);
   ```
3. In your cshtml:

   ```
   @model IEnumerable<SelectListItem>

   @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.RequestAreaName, Model)
   ```
4. If you need complecated object, you may need a wrapper class like:

   ```
    public class RaiseRequestModelWrapper
   {
   public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetModel { get; set; }
   public RaiseRequestModel PostModel { get; set; }
   }
   ```